# Server configuration for allowing custom domains to point to my saas app by just changing their nameservers to my own

Tags: nginx, saas

I have successfully built a saas application that allow its users to add custom domain names, my question is how do i configure my server for it to allow users point their domain name to my saas app by just changing their domain name servers to my saas app name servers eg. ns1.saasapp.com,ns2.saasapp.com my stack is Nginx php and mysql.

Answer (score 7):

Your customers should not have to change their Nameserver records. Instead, have them create a `CNAME` record pointing to the FQDN of your application and then ensure that your application is configured to properly serve requests with a `host` header that matches whatever name the customer created.